# How can I tell a child component to re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a page with a long list of items and a sidebar that shows details about each list item when an item is clicked. One of the components in my sidebar is a comments section that has 2 tabs, These comments are tied to the specific item that is clicked. What I want to happen is no matter which tab you've navigated to, when you click on a different list item, it jumps back to show tab 1. The tabs don't have any state tied to which one is shown. How can I pass down to the child to re-render when a different list item is clicked? here's a bit of what I'm looking at

```
class CommentsTabs extends React.Component<CommentsTabsProps> {
render() {
return (
  <TabsContainer panelClassName="md-grid" colored={true}>
    <Tabs tabId="simple-tab">{this.filterTabs(this.props.permissions)}</Tabs>
  </TabsContainer>
);
}

private filterTabs = (permissions: string[]): JSX.Element[] => {
const tabsArray: JSX.Element[] = [];
const canPostInternal = permissions.find(p => p === Permissions.PostInternalComments) ? true : false;
const canPostExternal = permissions.find(p => p === Permissions.PostExternalComments) ? true : false;

if (permissions.find(p => p === Permissions.ViewInternalComments)) {
  tabsArray.push(
    <Tab key={"internal-comments-tab"} style={{ marginLeft: 50 }} className={"active"} defaultTabIndex={0} label={"Internal Comments"} >
      {this.props.isFetching ? (
        <CircularProgress id="internal-comments-items-loading" />
      ) : (
        <Comments
          comments={this.props.internalComments}
          onPostComment={this.props.onInternalCommentPost}
          canPost={canPostInternal}
        />
      )}
    </Tab>
  );
}

if (permissions.find(p => p === Permissions.ViewExternalComments)) {
  tabsArray.push(
    <Tab key={"external-comments-tab"} defaultTabIndex={1} style={{ marginLeft: 50 }} label={"External comments"} >
      <Comments
        comments={this.props.externalComments}
        onPostComment={this.props.onExternalCommentPost}
        canPost={canPostExternal}
      />
    </Tab>
  );
}

return tabsArray;
```

If someone is looking at the `external-comments-tab`, and then they click on a different item in the list I want the default to be for it to re-render itself and reset to the focus be on the `internal-comments-tab`

Comment: What about handling componentReceiveProps and checking if previous and current links are different, set active tab to first tab?